# ALWAYS RETURN TO AN STATEMENT

Tags: php

I'm working with an simple validation php program and i have 2 files, 1 for display and 1 for control these are my codes:

```
 <form action="comp.php" method="post">     

                <input type="text" name="reading" placeholder="kilometer reading">
                <input type="date" name="date1" placeholder="date">
                <input type="text" name="suggest" placeholder="suggested kilometer"> 
                <input type="text" name="part" placeholder="spare part">   

            <input type="submit" class="button" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

and this is for my control:

```
$date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date1']));
$reading = $_POST['reading']; 
$suggest = $_POST['suggest'];
$part =$_POST['part'];

 $sql = "SELECT reading FROM sched ORDER BY reading DESC LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysqli_query($sqli, $sql);


      if (empty($_POST['reading']))
      {
        echo "No Input ";
        exit;
       }
        elseif ($_POST['reading'] < $result)
       {
        echo "Must input higher value than";
        exit;
       }
        elseif ($_POST['reading'] > $result)
       {
           if (($_POST['date1']) == "1970-01-01")
             {
            echo "no date input";
            exit;
           }
           else
           {
                $query = mysqli_query($sqli,"INSERT INTO sched (date,reading,suggest,part) VALUES ('$date1','$reading','$suggest','$part')");
            }
        }
}


mysqli_close($sqli);
header("Location: log.php");
```

My current highest reading is '15000'.
When my field `reading` is empty, the program works, but if I input values to my field it always return to `echo "Must input higher value than"; exit;`even if I input value higher that 15000. What the problem with this?

Comment: If you try fetching the result set it will work better, Currently `$result` will equal either `true` or `false` as a `mysqli_query()` return the status of the query execution and NOT the resulting resultset. When all else fails [Read the Flippin Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Comment: it is very good practice to use informative error messages, start with `echo 'Your input value ['.$_POST['reading'].'] is lower than ['.result.']';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_query()` just submits a query to the database for compilation and execution. It returns FALSE if there was an error in your query, so you need the test the returned value before continuing.

If the status is not FALSE, then $result will be a `mysqli_result` object that you can use to retrieve the resulting rows generated by your query.

```
$reading = $_POST['reading']; 
$suggest = $_POST['suggest'];
$part    = $_POST['part'];

$sql = "SELECT reading FROM sched ORDER BY reading DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($sqli, $sql);
if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
if (empty($_POST['reading'])) {
    echo "No Input ";
    exit;
}

if ($_POST['reading'] <= $row->reading) {
    echo "Must input higher value than {$row->reading}";
    exit;
}

if ($_POST['reading'] > $row->reading) {
    if (($_POST['date1']) == "1970-01-01") {
        echo "no date input";
        exit;
    } else {
        $query = mysqli_query($sqli,"INSERT INTO sched 
                                    (date,reading,suggest,part) 
                                    VALUES 
                                    ('$date1','{$row->reading}','$suggest','$part')");
    }
}
```

If you dont like simple objects being return from the query you can do

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if (empty($_POST['reading'])) {
        echo "No Input ";
        exit;
    }

    if ($_POST['reading'] <= $row['reading']) {
        echo "Must input higher value than {$row['reading']}";
        exit;
    }

    if ($_POST['reading'] > $row['reading']) {
        if (($_POST['date1']) == "1970-01-01") {
            echo "no date input";
            exit;
        } else {
            $query = mysqli_query($sqli,"INSERT INTO sched 
                                        (date,reading,suggest,part) 
                                        VALUES 
                                        ('$date1','{$row['reading']}','$suggest','$part')");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have a question is $row->reading Object Oriented? I am right? How to convert that to procedural

Comment: Yes, the `mysqli_fetch_object($result)` returns a row as an object with each columns from the SELECT as a property of `$row`